# Make feeds importer to replace instead rename file path

Tags: commerce, feeds

I am using commerce_feeds module to import products. It works well except the image fields url gets renamed by adding _0, _0_5, etc at the end of the image paths. How to turn this off? I would like to have path the same at all times no matter if the file is present with the particular path or not. Thank you for any help you can give in this regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server. It was not supporting image GD extension that prevented for generating images with a new path.